# regexp incorreclty split: by commas but not within brackets (both ) and ] )

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex idea: split by comma that is not followed by any character and ) or ]. 
Moreover, both brackets should be considred ( and [. Assumption: string contains valid brackets.

Here is my function:

```
function spl(str) {
    var reg = /\,(?!(?:[\w|\s]*\,?)*[\)\]])/;  
    console.log(str.split(reg));
}
```

Problems:

```
incorrectly: spl("tpr(7,4%), nitrita sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250)");
incorrectly: spl("tpr(7,4%), nitri(a,b,c[a,b])ta sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250),fsfs");
incorrectly: if there are brackets within brackets
```

Here is examples:

```
 str = "a,b (c,d,e)";
// expected: split into strings "a", "b (c,d,e)"

 str = "a,b [c,d,e]";
 // expected: split into strings "a", "b [c,d,e]"    

 str = "tpr(7,4%), nitrita sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250)";
 // expected split into "tpr(7,4%)", "nitrita sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250)"

 str = "tpr(7,4%), nitri(a,b,c[a,b])ta sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250),fsfs";
 //expected: "tpr(7,4%)", "nitri(a,b,c[a,b])ta sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250)" and "fsfs"

  str = "šokolāde 47% (cukurs, kakao sviests, (SOJAS); vanilīns), pulv";
  // expected: splited into two strings; "šokolāde 47% (cukurs, kakao sviests, (SOJAS); vanilīns)" and "pulv"
```

Comment: Have you an example before and after please

Comment: Yes, please include an input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative  lookahead assertion as in this regex:

```
/,\s*(?![^()]*\)|[^\]\[]*\])/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ygXJLY/3)

- `\s*,\s*`: Match comma surrounded by 0 or more whitespaces on either side
- `(?![^()]*\)|[^\]\[]*\])`: is a negative lookahead expression, that asserts that we don't have a `)` ahead following 0 or more non-round-bracket characters or don't have a `]` ahead following 0 or more non-square-bracket characters.

---

PS: Note that this regex solution work with non-nested and unescaped brackets only. For handling nested brackets of same type use a **parser code** as below.

```js
var arr = ['a,b (c,d,e)', 'a,b [c,d,e]',
'tpr(7,4%), nitrita sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250)',
'tpr(7,4%), nitri(a,b,c[a,b])ta sals (sals- 1.2%, konservants E250),fsfs',
'šokolāde 47% (cukurs, kakao sviests, (SOJAS); vanilīns), pulv'];

for (var j=0, arrlen=arr.length; j < arrlen; j++)
  console.log("*** Pocessing:", arr[j], "=>", splitComma(arr[j]));

function splitComma(str) {
  var result = [];
  var lvl = {'rb':0, 'sb':0};
  var tmp = '';
  var cd = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    var ch = str.charAt(i);
    
    if (ch == '(')
      lvl['rb']++;
    else if (ch == '[')
      lvl['sb']++;

    if (lvl['rb'] + lvl['sb'] == 0 && ch == ',') {
      result.push(tmp.trim());
      tmp = '';
    }
    else
      tmp += ch;
      
    if (ch == ')')
      lvl['rb']--;
    else if (ch == ']')
      lvl['sb']--;
  }      
  result.push(tmp.trim());
  return(result);
}
```

Comment: Unfourtunately this doesn't work with brackets inside brackets. And my first regexp also doesn't.. Here is not working ex https://regex101.com/r/28mRWj/1

Comment: This solution is not for nested brackets. None of your examples had nested brackets of same type. In fact no Javascript regex is possible for nested brackets. You will have to write a parser for those cases.

Comment: Can you please update yoru answer with comment that it doens't work for nested and give some clues how to writer parser or something like that. So I can mark it as answer.

Comment: And would it help if we have assumpetion that nested could be only in two levels? I mean test (test2 (fdsafd)) and no more?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Even with 2 level nesting it not possible to know position of the comma.. whether outside all the brackets or in between 1st and 2nd level or inside the inner most...

Comment: Can you point me, please, something more about using "parser instead". how to parse this? Maybe there is already existing algorith, i cannot find yet.

Comment: Yes I am writing a basic parser for you. Wiat for couple of hours as I have few meeting. I will update the question later today.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle nesting, you're going to need to parse before you process, regex alone isn't going to handle it for you. This is not the best parser in the world, but it's off the top of my head and an example of the kind of thing you can write to handle this. Or just find a parser that's meant to handle this kind of use case

```js
var test = "m,oo (ba,a) mbo,ool [sdf,lkj (sdfl,kj)] sd,fjk"
            
            function groupStr(str, exclusionPairs){
                let charArr = str.split(''),
                    exclusionLookup = exclusionPairs.reduce((obj, pair) => { obj[pair[0]] = pair[1]; return obj }, {}),
                    arrayOfPieces = [],
                    pieceArray = [],
                    flaggedExclusion = null,
                    char
                
                while((char = charArr.shift()) !== undefined){
                    if(flaggedExclusion){
                        pieceArray.push(char)
                        if(char == flaggedExclusion){
                            arrayOfPieces.push({
                                str: pieceArray.join(""),
                                exclude: true
                            })
                            pieceArray = []
                            flaggedExclusion = null
                        }
                    } else if(exclusionLookup[char]){
                        if(pieceArray.length){
                            arrayOfPieces.push({
                                str: pieceArray.join(""),
                                exclude: false
                            })
                            pieceArray = []
                        }
                        pieceArray.push(char)
                        flaggedExclusion = exclusionLookup[char]
                    } else {
                        pieceArray.push(char)
                    }
                }
                
                if(pieceArray.length){
                    arrayOfPieces.push({
                        str: pieceArray.join(""),
                        exclude: false
                    })
                }
                
                console.log(arrayOfPieces)
                
                return arrayOfPieces
            }
            
            let result = groupStr(test, [
                ["(",")"],
                ["[","]"]
            ])
            
            
            let splitArray = result.reduce((arr, piece) => {
                if(piece.exclude) arr.push(piece.str)
                else arr = arr.concat(piece.str.split(","))
                
                return arr
            }, [])
            
            console.log(splitArray)
```