# Splitting comma separated regex input string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given a comma separated regex string, for example:

```
^test\d+.txt$, ^[-,0-9]+$ // provided by user
```

I want to split it by a comma and get

- ^test\d+.txt$
- ^[-,0-9]+$

instead of

- ^test\d+.txt$
- ^[-
- 0-9]+$

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you change the way this is retrieved from the user and use a better delimiter?  If there can be a variable number of delimiters this is not going to be possible with 100% accuracy I think.

Comment: Probably you can't. There are too many ways to write a regex involving a comma that you won't be able handle them all without _some kind of constraint on how your input must be formatted_. A double pipe: (`||`) might be a good alternative delimiter, since it's rare in regex to need to repeat a character.

Comment: You have *no way* of telling whether a comma could be inside a regex or not. A `$` doesn't have to be the end of a regex, and a regex doesn't have to end with a `$`.

Comment: You need to write a parser for this. There's no other *proper* way. A hacky way of doing this, however is to use [`(?<=\$),\s*(?=\^)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%24%29%2c%5cs*%28%3f%3d%5c%5e%29&i=%5etest%5cd%2b.txt%24%2c+%5e%5b-%2c0-9%5d%2b%24&r=%5cn)

Comment: What you need is a regex to parse your regex, so you can do regex with a regex while you regex.

Comment: @Amy regception?

Comment: Comma shouldn't be delimiter here. You need a more different rare character or characters to do an identifier job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regexp incorreclty split: by commas but not within brackets (both ) and \] )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299201/regexp-incorreclty-split-by-commas-but-not-within-brackets-both-and)

Comment: There's an example parser as an answer on that question, although it's written in javascript

Comment: @jmcgriz That's trying to parse a well-defined format (split on commas that aren't inside brackets), not this (split on a comma that's not part of a regex)

Comment: @Rawling The characters may not be exactly the same, but the base question is - how to ignore characters inside of defined bounds using regex. And the answer is also the same - you can't really, and you shouldn't. You need to use a parser of some sort first.

Comment: @jmcgriz That doesn't help with the underlying problem, which is that a comma is a valid part of a regex so you can't even parse it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from the comments `,` is both a valid symbol within a regex and depending on the favor a valid delimiter in it's own right (for example in a qualifier).  As such it's not possible to separate regex's delimited by ','.  I suspect it would not matter what character you used there would still be ambiguity between the symbol chosen as a delimiter and an expression that contains that character.  In your example you comment that the input is `provided by user`.  If you have control over this input process you can might be able to change the delimiter to something different, for example if you know that only one language is in play you can use a unique character from a different language (assuming code is inserting the character and not the user directly).  Of course the best solution is to pass this information in an array (one regex per element).

In the end it depends on a lot of things.  Regex's are vulnerable to problems like infinite backtracking, which can be a problem when you are allowing arbitrary regex processing.  Again if you have control of the input process you might consider providing users a simpler template like language, so input like "AAAAA 99" (by user) could be converted to "[\w]{5} [\d]{2}" by code.  This is simpler for the user and allows you more control over how much chaos user input can create.

If you can not modify/control the input process, then you should teach your users to code regular expressions, perhaps by pointing them to the [quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). So they can create a single expression that does everything they want.

Anytime you are running a unknown regex you should use the methods that allow you to provide a timeout in order to protect against regex's that longer than you want to wait to finish.

Summary.  There's no good answer.  There is ambiguity between what you chose as a delimiter and what a valid regex can contain.  Your best bet is to change form of the input or the behavior of the user.